# Confused About What PCIe2 Slots Are Compatible

Tags: ssd, pci-express

I'm in the progress of updating my Workstation to speed up development on our database.

I like the look of this drive OCZ 120GB RevoDrive 3 PCI-E SSD but am having trouble working out if is compatible with any of my PCIe2 slots. My machine currently has the following free PCIe2 slots

- PCIe2 x8(4)
- PCIe2 x16
- PCIe x8(4)
- PCIe2 x16
- PCIe2 x16(8)

On the spec for the drive it says the interface is "PCI-Express Gen. 2 x4 interface". Which of the free slots I have would that be if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you one one hand have versions of PCI-E standard (each version is twice as fast as previous) and on the other hand you have the number of lanes each slot has. They can range form x1 to x32. On the third "hand" you have mechanical size of the slot and number of lanes the slot is connected to.

So the specification asks for a version 2 PCI-E slot (which is compatible with version 1, but version 2 device will work slower) and a slot which has at least 4 lanes.

Another thing is that a slot can be mechanically of one size and have a smaller number of lanes available. The device should then work more slowly, but should work.

So in your particular case, the best slot would be the PCIe2 x8(4) slot.

It's a second version PCI-E slot which is the 8 lane slot but only has 4 lanes. When you insert the SSD, it won't populate the entire slot, but that's OK. The SSD should work correctly.

Comment: +1: That's a much longer answer than I would have written :)